# How to translate Excel BDH formula into Python API code

Tags: python, bloomberg

I need help translating the below BDH formula from excel into python code using the BBG API. Specifically, I need to query only the weekly data for the particular index but my current python code is only returning daily. Is there a way to set specific criteria in python similar to how you query in Excel?

```
=@BDH(AAIIBEAR Index,PX_LAST,Start Date,End DAte,"Dir=V","fill=#N/A","Per=W","Days=A","Dts=H","cols=1;rows=1783")
```

Currently, I have built this Python code which queries the data in daily increments but need it to return weekly.

```
import os 
from blp import blp 
import pdblp 
import blpapi
import datetime 
import xlwings 
import pandas as pd

with open(os.path.join(os.getenv("TEMP"), "Bloomberg", "log", "bbcomm.log"),"r") as f: 
    try:
        port = f.read().split("BLOOMBERG COMMUNICATION SERVER READY on Port: ")[-1].split("\n")[0]
    except:
        port = 8194

con = pdblp.BCon(debug = False, port = 8194, timeout = 100000)
con.start()
today = datetime.datetime.today()

#assign tickers
bbg = con.bdh(['AAIIBEAR Index','PX_LAST', start_date="20240210",end_date= "20240220")
bbg = bbg.resample('D').ffill()
print (bbg)

#print data to excel 
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'X:\Public\Employee folders\fvan\Market.xlsx') as writer:
    bbg.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data', startcol=1)
```

I am expecting to return bloomberg data in weekly increments rather than daily. Is there a way to set this kind of criteria when querying in Python?

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: I don't know the Python API, but maybe `resample('W')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has serendipitously chosen a security that is only updated weekly (on a Thursday), hence there is no adjustment needed. The line `bbg = bbg.resample('D').ffill()` is then coercing this weekly data into daily data, which is not what is wanted here.

If a security does actually have daily data, then the options are passed to the `bdh()` call by the `elms` parameter. The Excel `=BDH()` call uses different option names compared to `pdblp` (which uses the underlying Bloomberg API).

The mapping can be found on Page 92 of the [Bloomberg API Guide](https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf), but I've extracted the relevant ones here (the doc also gives the alternative values for these parameters for different manipulations).

| Excel BDH() parameter | API option | Option Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fill=#N/A | nonTradingDayFillMethod | NIL_VALUE |
| Per=W | periodicitySelection | WEEKLY |
| Days=A | nonTradingDayFillOption | ALL_CALENDAR_DAYS |

Putting this together:

```
import pdblp

con = pdblp.BCon() 
con.start()

dtStart = '20240202'
dtEnd = '20240220'

df = con.bdh('INDU Index','PX_LAST',dtStart,dtEnd,
             elms=[('periodicitySelection','WEEKLY'),
                   ('nonTradingDayFillOption','ALL_CALENDAR_DAYS'),
                   ('nonTradingDayFillMethod','NIL_VALUE'),
                   ('periodicityAdjustment','ACTUAL')])
```

Note: The final parameter I have added is `periodicityAdjustment`. This governs whether the start or the end date is used for the weekly reference.

Using `periodicityAdjustment` set to `ACTUAL`, the last day of the period is the reference, and the weekly days are counted back from that:

```
ticker  INDU Index
field   PX_LAST
date    
2024-02-06  38xxx.xx
2024-02-13  38xxx.xx
2024-02-20  38xxx.xx
```

Using `periodicityAdjustment` set to `CALENDAR`, the starting date is the reference and the weeks are counted forward from that:

```
ticker  INDU Index
field   PX_LAST
date    
2024-02-02  38xxx.xx
2024-02-09  38xxx.xx
2024-02-16  38xxx.xx
```